# Importing .jar written in Java to Android, noClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on a small android-based project (I'm pretty new to the system). When I run the code on an Android emulator it crashes and I get the `noClassDefFoundError`. The .jar I'm trying to import is a very simple class written as a Java project. The error is not Android dependencies or 'lib/libs'.

The .jars (which I'm importing from the dropboxAPI) are working just fine (after getting the dependencies straight) but the same fix does not work for my .jar.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
// S verker

[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] Android Launch!
[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] Performing com.example.dropdolist.DropDoList activity launch
[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator    'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Galaxy2v3'
[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] Device API version is 16 (Android 4.1.2)
[2012-11-22 20:25:58 - DropDoList] Uploading DropDoList.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-11-22 20:26:02 - DropDoList] Installing DropDoList.apk...
[2012-11-22 20:26:11 - DropDoList] Success!
[2012-11-22 20:26:11 - DropDoList] Starting activity com.example.dropdolist.DropDoList on device emulator-5554
[2012-11-22 20:26:12 - DropDoList] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]  cmp=com.example.dropdolist/.DropDoList }
[2012-11-22 20:41:10 - DropDoList] Dx 
trouble processing:
[2012-11-22 20:41:10 - DropDoList] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing Tester/Transaction.class
...while processing Tester/Transaction.class
[2012-11-22 20:41:10 - DropDoList] Dx 
trouble processing:
[2012-11-22 20:41:10 - DropDoList] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing test/Tester.class
...while processing test/Tester.class
[2012-11-22 20:41:10 - DropDoList] Dx 2 warnings
```

Comment: Does the jar use any java APIs not available on Android? Which Jar is it? Where in your project is it located?

Comment: The class contained in the jar is really simple, just some basic attributes (no imports at all), I've imported it with the import function in eclipse, and the added with 'add jar' in the build path. It shows correctly in android dependencies.

Comment: Yes, along with the working jars from the dropboxAPI

Comment: When you build the project, do you see any errors in the console about certain code being not converted to dalvik or dex format?

Comment: I can add that
Transaction t = null;
works, and 
Transaction t = new Transaction();
does not

Comment: Could you create a small sample project that demoes this behaviour?

Comment: Will do, updated the question with the output from the console during startup

Comment: Java 7. JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]

Comment: I've created a small sample project, how should i send it?

Comment: I've added an answer. If that doesn't solve your problem, we can take this to chat and see what needs to be done.

Comment: I will try it, big thanks for taking the time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version` for two of your classes. This error will not stop the build process. Instead, it will silently exclude these files from the final compiled apk.

You will get this error if you are using (say) Java 5 and you are using a JAR compiled with Java 6.

The easiest way to resolve is to upgrade your version of Java to the one used by the JAR. You can change the version use for building by going to `Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler` and checking the `Enable project specific settings` box and changing the `Compiler compliance level:` value.

Android Tools don't play nice with Java 7, and you get a ton of `@Override` errors when using Java 5, so I'd recommend using Java 6 (which would be 1.6 in the compiler compliance dropdown). You may have to install it anew if it isn't already present.

Comment: It works, Thank you! I'd never have found that error by myself